# unused expression, expected an assignment or function call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am new to react. I am getting error on compile "unused expression, expected an assignment or function call" in the following code for button onClick.

```
handleClick = (itemClicked:PaymentTypes, e) => {
    <Route exact path="/ListSwipe" render={(props) =>  ( <ListSwipe vpType={itemClicked}/> )} />
}
```

Comment: what you are trying to achieve, can you explain the task?

Comment: Can you please provide some more information?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your intention to use `handleClick` function to use like that but the warning ( It shouldn't be an error, maybe a linter error) you have because of you are neither returning anything nor invoking a function here. Try to use it like this:

```
handleClick = (itemClicked:PaymentTypes, e) =>
    <Route exact path="/ListSwipe" render={(props) =>  ( <ListSwipe vpType={itemClicked}/> )} />
```

Comment: Thanks! issue is resolved but it giving another error "value must be set for boolean attributes".

Comment: I need to route to a component on table row selection so handleClick is event listener for the same

Comment: Please update your question and provide more information, code samples about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @AnjaliShahani, Can you please tel, how did you resolved this issue in your end?

Comment: @devserkan: What is the difference between your version without the `{}` and @anjali-shahani's version with them?

Comment: @4ndy, he uses a [block body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body) for the arrow function but does not use a `return`. Without block body ({}) a `return` isn't needed. I mean if we skip body block and use an implicit return there is no need for `return`. You can check the link I gave.